# How to disable menu shortcut in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

I would like to put alt+C as "comment" shortcut but it's conflicting with the alt+C shortcut that open the "Source" menu. This shortcut cannot be found in the shortcut options (Tools/Preferences/Keyboard shortcuts). It is possible to disable these menu shortcut ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, that's not possible. That shortcut is necessary to help people with disabilities navigate our interface with the keyboard only.

Comment: But, if i want to change a shortcut is not possible? im having a lot of troubles with thw Ctrl+Enter

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the maintainer. Better to leave like that. Nonetheless, here is short set of (personal) redefinition of shortcuts along with the "Functions"

New keybord shortcuts for runing scripts within Spyder IDE:

1. Run file
   default --> F5
   new     --> F1
2. Run current cell
   default --> Ctrl+Return
   new     --> F2
3. Run current cell (and advance)
   default --> shift + Return
   new     --> shift + F2
4. Run selection or current line
   default --> F9
   new     --> F3

Redifinig shortcuts to avoid clashes:
5) Spyder documentation
default --> F1
new     --> F4